# C# - Change index of ComboBox item?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox that I want to be able to add items to the beginning of. For example, when you click it, you get 1,2,3 , but I want to be able to add an option, 0, so that when you click it you get 0,1,2,3.

Is this possible without rebuilding the combobox?

Comment: what do you mean with our rebuilding? 
i am sure Combobox.Add API should be able to help you to add what ever you want.

Comment: @zenwalker The "Add" method always inserts at the end of the item list.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Do you want to add/insert items into combo or want to change index for selection purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.insert.aspx) method of the Items property of the combo box:

```
myComboBox.Items.Insert(0, "New item at top");
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the `Insert()` method on the `Items` property of your `ComboBox` object.

```
var comboBox = new ComboBox();
comboBox.Items.Add("1");
comboBox.Items.Add("2");
comboBox.Items.Add("3");
comboBox.Items.Insert(0, "0");
```